# Center contents of Bootstrap row, but justify when column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to know if there's a way in Bootstrap to have the contents of a `col-*` element within a `row` to be aligned left or right when arranged as columns, but for the contents to be aligned *center* when arranged as rows.

For example, take this simple row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

When displayed as columns, the contents of each div should be aligned left and aligned right, respectively. But when viewed as rows in a smaller view port, they should be centered.

Comment: Add class as default alignment text-left and use media queries to detect the view port to  align it at center.

Answer (score 2):

You can use media queries as follow:

```
.text-center-xs {
    text-align: center;
}    
.text-left-xs {
    text-align: left;
}    
.text-right-xs {
    text-align: right;
}


/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */    
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .text-center-sm {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .text-left-sm {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .text-right-sm {
        text-align: right;
    }
}


/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */    
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .text-center-md {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .text-left-md {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .text-right-md {
        text-align: right;
    }
}


/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */    
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .text-center-lg {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .text-left-lg {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .text-right-lg {
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-center-xs text-left-sm">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center-xs text-right-sm">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/5qkr7c5o/ (try to resize the output to see the result !)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an out-of-the-box predefined solution using bootstrap. Bootstrap does have alignment classes but they aren't designed to change across breakpoints the same way their grid/column classes are. That said you can do it yourself using media queries.

```
.custom-align-left,
.custom-align-right {
  text-align:center;
}

// this is when col-sm comes into play
@media(min-width:768px){
 .custom-align-left {
   text-align:left;
 }
 .custom-align-right {
   text-align:right;
 }
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 custom-align-left">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 custom-align-right">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the effect shown below, you need to edit / override the standard bootstrap settings in the bootstrap.(min).css file.

```
<div class="row">
*centered text*
<div class="col-sm-8">
    *left/right aligned text*
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    *left/right aligned text*
</div>
```

The .col-* part:
The standard .col-xx-xx items are all floated left by bootstrap directly.

You can add a .col-*{ float: right;} to your personal .css file.  But then you need to ensure your include statement is after the bootstrap.css listing. (Best Option)

Or you could directly edit your bootstrap.(min).css file.

Or you can just use brute force in your own .css file by adding the "!important" as shown.

Or you can break all the rules and just put a style="text-align:right !important" statement in whatever tag you want.  But this is awful.

[from CSS Tricks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh8vv.jpg)

https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

The .row Part:

Bootstrap doesn't have anything for alignment in there for just .row classes.
As such you should find it much easier for your .css elements to take effect.

Add a .row {text-align:center;} to your included .css file.

Comment: using `!important` is not necessary, just need to add two classes for aligning left and right, then center them both inside media query rule,https://jsfiddle.net/3tgyxs7k/1/

Comment: Honestly if you are just learning, !important may be something you pull out when CSS has you on the last thread, trying to figure out why it won't let you change some formatting.

Comment: It should be use as last resort, when you have no other way to fix the problem except if you using it, from this [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception), **rule #1** says **`Always `** `look for a way to use specificity before even considering !important` when talking about The !important exception, so since there's another way to fix it, better to avoid this exception. at least IMHO